# How do I set a DynamoDB attribute to an empty list?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to set an attribute in a DynamoDB document to an empty list via an update request, using the DynamoDBv2 library from the AWS SDK for .NET.

I've tried the obvious update expression, with no success:

```
// Fails, expression attribute values cannot contain an empty list
...
ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
    { ":empty", new AttributeValue { L = new List<AttributeValue> { } } },
},
UpdateExpression = "SET #P.MyList = :empty",
...
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer after digging through the AWS SDK source code. The key is that the `IsLSet` property is settable. This calls the following code:

```
public static void SetIsSet<T>(bool isSet, ref List<T> field)
{
    if (isSet)
        field = new AlwaysSendList<T>(field);
    else
        field = new List<T>();
}
```

When determining if your AttributeValue is initialised, is uses the following code:

```
public static bool GetIsSet<T>(List<T> field)
{
    if (field == null)
        return false;

    if (field.Count > 0)
        return true;

    var sl = field as AlwaysSendList<T>;
    if (sl != null)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

This also shows why using `new AttributeValue { L = new List<AttributeValue> { } }` doesn't have the intended effect - this method will return false as the `Count` is 0. However, the check for the special `AlwaysSendList` type will return true if you've set the `IsLSet` property.

Back to your code, the answer is to use the following:

```
...
ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
    { ":empty", new AttributeValue { IsLSet = true } },
},
UpdateExpression = "SET #P.MyList = :empty",
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Just ran across this problem myself. Looks like a bug that's been around since at least November 2018 ( https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1116 ). My workaround was to manually set `IsLSet = true` immediately after you set the value of `L`.

For example, here is how you would create an empty list attribute:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> 
{
    { ":empty", new AttributeValue { L = new List<AttributeValue>(), IsLSet = true }},
},
UpdateExpression = "SET #P.MyList = :empty",
```

You should be able to use the above syntax regardless of whether or not your list is empty.  For example:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> 
{
    { ":MyListOfValues", new AttributeValue { L = listValues, IsLSet = true }},
},
UpdateExpression = "SET #P.MyList = :MyListOfValues",
```

Answer (score 1):

For those encountering this issue in the Java SDK, I found the solution. Java doesn't seem to have an `IsLSet` analogy in its library. To specify an empty AttributeValue list for DynamoDB using Java, the following works:

```
AttributeValue.builder().l(new ArrayList<AttributeValue>()).build();
```

For Example,

```
String updateExpression = "SET my_list = :empty_list";
Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = Map.of(
    ":empty_list", AttributeValue.builder().l(new ArrayList<AttributeValue>()).build()
    );
```